# Прошу определить истинный адрес

Tags: javascript

Доброго дня!
Прошу помощи, т.к. не разбираюсь в JS...
Есть страница, в которой прикреплены JS и с помощью их она наполняется информацией из источника на том же сервере... помогите определить прямую ссылку на источник...

Страница: [страница с контентом](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/fx/g10/euro-fx_quotes_volume_voi.html)

в центральной ее части - таблицы... данные из этих таблиц мне и нужны....
мне удалось определить, что класс таблиц: "opTables"

Видимо 2 скрипта участвуют в заполнении данными:

1. _http://www.cmegroup.com/javascript/cmeUtil.js
2. _http://www.cmegroup.com/javascript/voi.js

а в них,похоже, передается:

**[script type="text/javascript"]
     $j(document).ready(function(){
          Global.cme.events.voiProduct.on_load();
     });
[/script]**

и

**[script type="text/javascript"]
    Global.cme.productID = "58";
    Global.cme.type = "OF";
    Global.cme.foi = "FUT";
    Global.cme.productCd ="6E";
    Global.cme.exchangeCd ="XCME";
    Global.cme.venue ="G";
    Global.cme.f = "FUT";
    Global.cme.CPCOnly ="false";
[/script]**

Был бы крайне признателен за помощь! Спасибо, друзья!

Comment: Владислав, дружище! Уж и не знаю как благодарить!!! Большущее спасибо!!!
Там еще одна таблица есть "JAN 14 Calls", но попытаюсь поперебирать/подставлять данные в адрес... может что-то и получится...

Comment: а! Там они все внизу... торможу... )))
СПАСИБИЩЕ!!!! Ежели чем могу помочь - обращайся!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я открыл страницу нажал F12 открыл вкладку network (в Chrome) и увидел что данные приходят прямо в HTML, вот по такому URL:

```
http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/xsltTransformer.do?xlstDoc=/XSLT/md/voi/detail_page_template.xsl&url=/da/VOI/V2/Details/TradeDate/20131220/DetailType/FUTURES_DETAILS/ProductId/58/ReportType/P&html
```

и

```
http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/xsltTransformer.do?xlstDoc=/XSLT/md/voi/options_table_template.xsl&url=/da/VOI/V2/Details/TradeDate/20131220/ProductId/58/OptionType/AME/ReportType/P&html
```